# Nested Objects to Adapter

Tags: android, json, kotlin

So from what I understand I have set up the classes to read the following correctly. However when I go to send just the episodes object to the adapter in kotlin I run into a small issue - I can't send it over.

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val podcastepisodes = gson.fromJson(body, PodcastFeed::class.java)
val epsiodeFeed = gson.fromJson(podcastepisodes.programs, PodcastProgram::class.java)
Thread {
    runOnUiThread {
        binding.recyclingViewDRN1Shows.adapter = MainProgramAdapter(epsiodeFeed)
    }
}.start()
```

My class files to read JSON data are:

```
//FETCH EPISODES
class PodcastFeed(val programs: List<PodcastProgram>)

class PodcastProgram(val episode: List<EpisodeFeed>)

class EpisodeFeed(val title: String, val description: String, val enclosureurl: String)
```

and the JSON looks like this.

JSON Result.

```
{
  "programs": [
    {
      "_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
      "title": "Bounce Back Comedy",
      "link": "http://drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback",
      "icon": "https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/bounceback_logo.png",
      "banner": "https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/BounceBackBanner.jpg",
      "url": "bounceback",
      "category": "Comedy",
      "subcategory": "",
      "hosts": [
        "Yvonne Fletcher"
      ],
      "description": "Get ready for a laugh or two with Bounce Back Comedy with Yvonne Fletcher. Each week she invites comedians to chat about their comedy journeys. This show shares some comedy insight and will have you laughing along the way.",
      "subtitle": "Get ready for a laugh or two with Bounce Back Comedy with Yvonne Fletcher. Each week she invites comedians to chat about their comedy journeys. This show shares some comedy insight and will have you laughing along the way.",
      "summary": "Get ready for a laugh or two with Bounce Back Comedy with Yvonne Fletcher. Each week she invites comedians to chat about their comedy journeys. This show shares some comedy insight and will have you laughing along the way.",
      "explicit": "yes",
      "station": [
        "DRN1"
      ],
      "day-air": [
        "Thursday"
      ],
      "starttime-air": [
        "19:00:00"
      ],
      "endtime-air": [
        "20:00:00"
      ],
      "active": true,
      "itunes_link": "https://podcasts.apple.com/au/podcast/bounce-back/id1513169177",
      "stitcher_link": "",
      "spotify": "https://open.spotify.com/show/5UEQ8rV0DwUaBZRpNCDcUm",
      "iheart": "https://iheart.com/podcast/78094818/",
      "episode": [
        {
          "_id": "60a7b8ab3f2d2a7d7e5159e1",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": 2,
          "episode_no": 8,
          "title": "Stand Up for India",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back join show host Yvonne Fletcher and Gill The Scottish Terrier, Gemma Frances and Hoursty representing a few of the comedians supporting The Open Mic Comedy Night Stand Up for India presented by NY Events! This event will donate $5 per ticket sold to Sewa Internationals appeal to assist India during their current COVID-19 crisis.",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back join show host Yvonne Fletcher and Gill The Scottish Terrier, Gemma Frances and Hoursty representing a few of the comedians supporting The Open Mic Comedy Night Stand Up for India presented by NY Events! This event will donate $5 per ticket sold to Sewa Internationals appeal to assist India during their current COVID-19 crisis.</p><p>Could we please add comedy fundraising  event tickets available <a href=\"https://www.nyevents.com.au/comedy\" alt=\"NYEvents Comedy\" target=\"_blank\">www.nyevents.com.au/comedy</a> #comedy #perthradiostation #perth #perthlife #comedian #australia #digitalradio #covid19 #standupcomedy</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/2/8",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season2/S02E08.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": "58315527",
          "pubDate": "2021-05-21T00:00:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "01:00:44",
          "explicit": "no"
        },
        {
          "_id": "60961f67fc25531d0c80fef0",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": 2,
          "episode_no": 7,
          "title": "Writer and comedian David Hughes",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show, host Yvonne Fletcher is joined in the studio with writer and comedian David Hughes. David shares his experience as a writer for comedians and how he then started his very own journey into stand up comedy!",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show, host Yvonne Fletcher is joined in the studio with writer and comedian David Hughes.</p><p>David shares his experience as a writer for comedians and how he then started his very own journey into stand up comedy!</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/2/7",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season2/S02E07.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": "142282916",
          "pubDate": "2021-05-08T10:00:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "00:59:17",
          "explicit": "no"
        },
        {
          "_id": "6083b52174bfba0d22062f42",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": 2,
          "episode_no": 6,
          "title": "Melbourne Comedian Jarryd Goundrey",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined in the studio with Melbourne Comedian Jarryd Goundrey. Join them for a chat about comedy, family and touring during covid 19.",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined in the studio with Melbourne Comedian Jarryd Goundrey.</p><p>Join them for a chat about comedy, family and touring during covid 19.</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/2/6",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season2/S02E06.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": "58922589",
          "pubDate": "2021-04-24T13:32:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "01:01:23",
          "explicit": "no"
        },
        {
          "_id": "6073c429bc7526dab5e7aa4c",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "2",
          "episode_no": "5",
          "title": "Definitely not your everyday school teacher Miss Samia",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined Miss Samia who's definitely not your everyday school teacher but Perths fast emerging stand up comedian! She's been the 2019 Red Bull Competition Semi Finalist and the 2020 State RAW finalist. Miss Samia shares intimately her survival story after dying from anaphylactic shock and her journey with her mums ovarian cancer.",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined Miss Samia who's definitely not your everyday school teacher but Perths fast emerging stand up comedian! She's been the 2019 Red Bull Competition Semi Finalist and the 2020 State RAW finalist. Miss Samia shares intimately her survival story after dying from anaphylactic shock and her journey with her mums ovarian cancer.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/2/5",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season2/S02E05.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 56803697,
          "pubDate": "2021-04-12T03:55:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "00:59:10",
          "explicit": "no"
        },
        {
          "_id": "6068514becc45cae6aa4d163",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "2",
          "episode_no": "4",
          "title": "Perth's very own Gill the Scottish Terrier and Leonie Clarke ",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined Gill the Scottish Terrier and Leonie Clarke sharing in a laugh about marriage, FRINGE WORLD and the development of their show old farts.",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined Gill the Scottish Terrier and Leonie Clarke sharing in a laugh about marriage, FRINGE WORLD and the development of their show old farts.</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/2/4",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season2/S02E04.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 57680256,
          "pubDate": "2021-04-03T11:27:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "01:00:05",
          "explicit": "no"
        },
        {
          "_id": "60586dee01e01e05114f689e",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "2",
          "episode_no": "3",
          "title": "The Mebourne International Comedy Festival's national competition Class Clowns!",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is checking out The Mebourne International Comedy Festival's national competition Class Clowns! She's joined by previous WA winner of two years Jackson Mark Canny and two contestants from this year's 2021 heat and finals brothers (her very own  children) Odin and Lars. Class Clowns is a comedy competition ideally for 14-18 year olds and runs nationally each year. Be sure not to miss your opportunity to partake in next year.",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is checking out The Mebourne International Comedy Festival's national competition Class Clowns! She's joined by previous WA winner of two years Jackson Mark Canny and two contestants from this year's 2021 heat and finals brothers (her very own  children) Odin and Lars. Class Clowns is a comedy competition ideally for 14-18 year olds and runs nationally each year. Be sure not to miss your opportunity to partake in next year.</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/2/3",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season2/S02E03.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 26908532,
          "pubDate": "2021-03-22T10:14:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "00:28:02",
          "explicit": "no"
        },
        {
          "_id": "604c28e29327971a58a880e4",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "2",
          "episode_no": "2",
          "title": "Stevie Belowsky - Stand-up comic, poet, stage and screen writter!",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined Stevie Belowsky - stand-up comic, poet, stage and screen writter! Belowsky discusses his new book release 'Stay Greasy Baby'!",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>Stevie Belowsky - stand-up comic, poet, stage and screen writter!  Belowsky discusses his new book release 'Stay Greasy Baby'!</p><p>We enjoy some poem recites and end the episode with Belowsky showcasing his latest music single release 'Hook's Jab's Word's'!</p><p>#comedy #perthradiostation #perth #perthlife #perthtodo #perthisok #international #poet #comedian #westernaustralia #belowsky</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/2/2",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season2/S02E02.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 92095134,
          "pubDate": "2021-03-13T02:50:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "01:03:56",
          "explicit": "yes"
        },
        {
          "_id": "6037287e317e473252456bf9",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "2",
          "episode_no": "1",
          "title": "Comedian Rapper Chris Turner",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined Comedian Rapper Chris Turner in the USA! We get to know Chris a little more by exploring his comedy journey and he shares a few of the really important lessons he learnt about himself along the way. This episode ends with Chris showcasing his humour and wit with him creating an on the spot rap!",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined Comedian Rapper Chris Turner in the USA!</p><p>We get to know Chris a little more by exploring his comedy journey and he shares a few of the really important lessons he learnt about himself along the way.</p><p>This episode ends with Chris showcasing his humour and wit with him creating an on the spot rap!</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/2/1",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season2/S02E01.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 67314138,
          "pubDate": "2021-02-25T11:00:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "01:07:17",
          "explicit": "yes"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5fe43be69e76a930f3a953ef",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "1",
          "episode_no": "33",
          "title": "Comedian Alli Butler",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined by ex Sydney sider come Western Australian regional comedian, songwriter, musician Alli Butler! They explore online dating, venture down the garden path of female grooming and chat about babies, birth and Alli's sensational show 40 Year Old Popstar!",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined by ex Sydney sider come Western Australian regional comedian, songwriter, musician Alli Butler! They explore online dating, venture down the garden path of female grooming and chat about babies, birth and Alli's sensational show 40 Year Old Popstar!</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/1/33",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season1/S01E33.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 67314138,
          "pubDate": "2020-12-24T04:00:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "01:10:07",
          "explicit": "yes"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5fda06d63c22620cde45fcd4",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "1",
          "episode_no": "32",
          "title": "The crew from Classy Comedy",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher has the crew from Classy Comedy joining her. The trio share their stories in comedy included situations involving a few heated audience memebers. Lookout for their FRINGE WORLD show “The Incorrect Standup Comedy Show”",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher has the crew from Classy Comedy joining her. The trio share their stories in comedy included situations involving a few heated audience memebers. Lookout for their FRINGE WORLD show  “The Incorrect Standup Comedy Show”</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/1/32",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season1/S01E32.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 70536512,
          "pubDate": "2020-12-16T04:00:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "01:01:21",
          "explicit": "yes"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5fd1ef09a279276f694d5a52",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "1",
          "episode_no": "31",
          "title": "WA Regional comedian Squirly.",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher catches up with regional comedian Squirly.",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher chats with regional comedian Squirly and we find out what is it like to be a comedian in Exmouth, Western Australia approximately 1,250 kms North of Perth.</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/1/31",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season1/S01E31.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 74333331,
          "pubDate": "2020-12-10T04:00:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "00:51:36",
          "explicit": "no"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5fc8f41cfea32129636e3fc7",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "1",
          "episode_no": "30",
          "title": "London comedian Nic Monisse.",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher catches up with London comedian Nic Monisse.",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher catches up with London comedian Nic Monisse.</p><p>Nic shares his experience in comedy worldwide and  discusses his passion for urban design. Nic has directed and hosted documentaries on urbanism and is a published writer. We also explore what it's been like to be returning to lockdown in London.</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/1/30",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season1/S01E30.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 53506509,
          "pubDate": "2020-12-03T04:00:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "00:55:44",
          "explicit": "no"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5fc8f380fea32129636e3fc6",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "1",
          "episode_no": "29",
          "title": " International comedian Brodi Snook",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined by international comedian Brodi Snook who has returned to her hometown Busselton in regional Western Australia after Covid 19 hit. Brodi shares her story as a comedian overseas and how situations have shaped her growth.",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined by international comedian Brodi Snook who has returned to her hometown Busselton in regional Western Australia after Covid 19 hit. Brodi shares her story as a comedian overseas and how situations have shaped her growth.</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/1/29",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season1/S01E29.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 85460868,
          "pubDate": "2020-11-26T04:00:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "00:59:20",
          "explicit": "no"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5fb640f5479d8296d8ca3382",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "1",
          "episode_no": "28",
          "title": "FRINGE WORLD 2021 | Three Broke Gays",
          "summary": "Join show host Yvonne Fletcher on Bounce Back and share in the laughs and great conversation with the fabulous trio comedians Cody Lam, Charlotte Glance and Jackson Canny all from up and coming FRINGE WORLD show 'Three Broke Gays'!",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>Join show host Yvonne Fletcher on Bounce Back and share in the laughs and great conversation with the fabulous trio comedians Cody Lam, Charlotte Glance and Jackson Canny all from up and coming FRINGE WORLD show 'Three Broke Gays'!</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/1/28",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season1/S01E28.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 62467701,
          "pubDate": "2020-11-19T04:00:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "01:05:04",
          "explicit": "yes"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5facf15c1812b61ea9cc1063",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "1",
          "episode_no": "27",
          "title": "Comedian/MC/Songwriter Matt Storer",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined by Comedian/MC/Songwriter Matt Storer! Matt cleverly combines stand-up and musical comedy has earnt recognition across Australia and the UK!",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined by Comedian/MC/Songwriter Matt Storer! Matt cleverly combines stand-up and musical comedy has earnt recognition across Australia and the UK!</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/1/27",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season1/S01E27.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": 55676625,
          "pubDate": "2020-11-12T05:40:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "00:57:59",
          "explicit": "yes"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5fa3e4116582adbd86b1d70d",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "1",
          "episode_no": "26",
          "title": "Melbourne Comedian Jez Watts",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined by Melbourne comedian Jez Watts and they're talking about lockdowns, shrooms and everything grand about stand up comedy",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher is joined by Melbourne comedian Jez Watts and they're talking about lockdowns, shrooms and everything grand about stand up comedy.</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/1/26",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season1/S01E26.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": "62360185",
          "pubDate": "2020-11-05T05:40:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "01:04:57",
          "explicit": "yes"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f9a883dfc39ee8128bfa701",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "1",
          "episode_no": "25",
          "title": "ex veterans Jarryd Goundrey and Micheal Gledhill",
          "summary": "Tonight on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher has ex veterans come, comedians, Jarryd Goundrey and Micheal Gledhill!  These ex-service members share some of their humour, and talk about veterans, comedy and mental health issues, tune in!",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>Tonight on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher has ex veterans come, comedians, Jarryd Goundrey and Micheal Gledhill!  These ex-service members share some of their humour, and talk about veterans, comedy and mental health issues, tune in!</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/1/25",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season1/S01E25.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": "62411812",
          "pubDate": "2020-10-29T05:40:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "01:05:0",
          "explicit": "yes"
        },
        {
          "_id": "5f915ccaac10ef295db1ce4d",
          "show_id": "5ebbd61635b7609ba9b2d7bc",
          "show_b": "bounceback",
          "season": "1",
          "episode_no": "24",
          "title": "Celebrity Comedian Janelle Koenig",
          "summary": "This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher chews the rag with Perth's Celebrity Comedian Janelle Koenig! Janelle's comedy career spans over 15 years and she's performed both nationally and internationally! Janelle's witty sense of humour has you laughing both on and off the stage!",
          "description": "<![CDATA[<p>This week on Bounce Back show host Yvonne Fletcher chews the rag with Perth's Celebrity Comedian Janelle Koenig! Janelle's comedy career spans over 15 years and she's performed both nationally and internationally! Janelle's witty sense of humour has you laughing both on and off the stage!</p><p>Subscribe to the podcast to never miss an episode.</p>]]>",
          "link": "https://www.drn1.com.au/shows/bounceback/1/24",
          "enclosureurl": "storage.googleapis.com/radiomediapodcast/bounceback/season1/S01E24.mp3",
          "enclosurebyts": "57546656",
          "pubDate": "2020-10-22T05:40:00.201Z",
          "author": "Radio Media PTY LTD",
          "duration": "00:59:56",
          "explicit": "no"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to send it to

```
class PodcastEpisodeAdapter(val podcastFeed: PodcastFeed): RecyclerView.Adapter<ProgramViewHolder>() {

//CODE IN HERE
}
```

The issue is I can't seems to get it to send the episodes over to this.

Comment: Create an adapter with empty dataset when the view is created. Update the dataset once the data is ready and notify the recyclerView to refresh/repaint the data.

Comment: I realised all I need to do was podcastFeed.programs[0].episode.count()